# .rdlc report in c# does not display any output data?

Tags: c#, dataset, rdlc

My friends im using visual studio 2008,and i develop small project in c# , Now i want to add reports in it ,(.rdlc reports) . Here is my code

```
 try
        {
            reportViewer1.Reset();
            con.Open();
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "select_book_specific";

            param = new SqlParameter("@isbn", "isbn1");
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.DbType = DbType.String;
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(ds);


         //  for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; i++)
           // {

             //   MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][i].ToString());

            //} For testing purpose

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Report1.rdlc";


this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(newReportDataSource("Books",ds.Tables[0].TableName.ToString()));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


}
catch(exception ex){messageBox.show(ex.message);}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what is `newReportDataSource` can you show the code?

Comment: @lc-Sorry pal itz a mistake My question is Report does not display any data?

Comment: @Damith - it should be a space between the new keyword and ReportDatasource keyword it should be `new ReportDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
try
{
    reportViewer1.Reset();
    con.Open();
    command.Connection = con;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "select_book_specific";

    param = new SqlParameter("@isbn", "isbn1");
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Report1.rdlc";
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add( new ReportDataSource(ds.DataSetName + "_" + ds.TableName, ds.Tables[0]));
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    messageBox.show(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: When i add your answer at the end of my question , there is only reportViewer , and no report displayed , ,,

Comment: debug and see whether table having records before adding as report data source and also check the report path. are you get any exception? i have updated my answer with full code. please check.

Comment: There is no exception ,and i checked the dataset using for loop it is ok report path also correct , but there are no report displaying in reportVierwer